# Where are WhatsApp images stored in iphone? Is it in server or phone itself?

Tags: iphone, whatsapp

I actually hide all the WhatsApp images from Camera Roll. i just want to know where exactly these images are stored!

Sorry, This look like very simple one. But i need to know

PS:I am new to iPhone world

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.The images are stored on their server, that is how you can access when someone else posts an image.
2.The images that you have manually downloaded by clicking on a photo or autodownload is on, will be stored on your device locally be it the Iphone or android app
3. Use a file manager to find out location of Whatsapp image storage for your device. I doubt that it is same for all devices

Answer (score 3):

**WhatsApp** stores the downloaded media files inside the path:
`Library/Media/CONTACT_WHATSAPP_ID/`

**CONTACT_WHATSAPP_ID:**

1. if the contact is a person this id will be the contact mobile number followed by `@s.whatsapp.net` example: `970999999999@s.whatsapp.net`
2. if the contact is a group this id will be the group creator mobile number followed by the [epoch](http://www.epochconverter.com/) time stamp when this group was created followed by `@g.us`, example: `970999999999-1483006443@g.us`

I hope this can help someone.

Answer (score 0):

On the iPhone (iOS 13):

*Application Groups > net.whatsapp.WhatsApp.shared > Message > Media*